How to run async stored procedure with result set in Entity Framework Core
I have created stored procedure that create some report. Standard Id, UserName, NumOfSomething, Month.
Now I would like to get result of this stored procedure async. I can do it with standard sync way:
public async ValueTask<List<ReportDto>> GetReport(int managerId)
{
    var result = reportContext.Database.SqlQuery<ReportDto>($"MonthlyNumOfCasesPerUserReport @ManagerId = {managerId}").ToList();

    return result;
}

This code works quite good as it already map result into my entities but I would like to do it async.
I have already tried ToListAsync() but I get error:

System.InvalidOperationException: The source IQueryable doesn't
implement IDbAsyncEnumerable<CommonLibrary.Dto.ReportDto>. Only
sources that implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity
Framework asynchronous operations.


ToListAsync should work. Except if there is something between SqlQuery and ToListAsync which changes the EF Core query provider. Or some 3rd party extension intercepting EF queryable and replacing it with their own (e.g. LinqKit or similar).

My problem was that I had System.Data.Entity in using section :/

Problem was related to mixing Entity Framework and Entity Framework Core in one file. DbContext file had using System.Data.Entity (from EF) that was causing the problem.
